# How to open Finder on Mac using .NET MAUI with Mac Catalyst

Tags: .net-6.0, mac-catalyst, .net-maui

I'm using .NET MAUI and I need to **open Finder for a specific folder** (not picking a folder, I just want users to be able to see where files are stored). In Windows I use this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFolderPathAsync("<folder>")
```

But I can't find the equivalent for Mac Catalyst.